# Iterating through a list of characters in T-SQL

Tags: sql, loops, t-sql, for-loop

I am looking for any efficient way to solve the following problem in T-SQL:

```
for i in L = ['A', 'B',..., 'N'] 
INSERT INTO MyTable1 (SomeCol1, SomeCol2)
SELECT SomeCol1, SomeCol2 FROM SomeTable1 WHERE <conditions>
UPDATE MyTable1 SET MyCol1 = i WHERE MyCol1 = 'the default value of MyCol1'
```

Given that my list of characters `L` is long, I don't want to do this once for each element separately. So, if there is a better solution than using a loop, I am interested in that as well as long as it solves the issue. Please note that I am not trying to use correct syntax above - I would rather also like to know how to approach the part `for i in L = ['A', 'B',..., 'N']` in T-SQL.

Thanks!

Comment: Could you provide some sample data and expect result?

Comment: Your `UPDATE MyTable SET MyCol = i` make no sence if you didn't set the `where` condition, becuase `MyCol` will set as the last character from `L` list

Comment: I could but don't see how that would make things easier. The question would become very long and not-nice-to-read. All that matters (I think) is that I want to loop through a list of characters (or any other solution than a loop, where the amount of code doesn't increase with the length of my list).

Comment: There is a `WHERE` condition after `SET` that I left out, but I can update the question with that.

Comment: @CHRD given that *MyConditions* not depend on i - direct answer to your question would be UPDATE MyTable SET MyCol = 'N' - it will produce the same result. Please provide concrete example with WHERE dependant on i

Comment: @D-Shih you could assume that I want this nonsensical outcome and provide a solution that iterates through the list (even if the end result makes little sense). That would still solve my problem. But I will go ahead and update the question again if that is preferred.

Comment: @CHRD SQL is a set-based language. There's seldom any need to use loop.s That's certainly not one of those extremely rare cases. You can update a table based on a join, eg `Update MyTable  Set ... FROM MyTable inner join MyCharacterSource ...` As it is, the question is *very* unclear. Where do those characters come from? SQL doesn't have arrays. Do they come from a TVP, a view, a function?

Comment: @CHRD `There is a WHERE condition after SET that I left out, but I can update the question with that.` without it the questions is meaningles. You are simply replacing the *same* values over and over again, Might as well remove the loop and just write `UPDATE MyTable SET MyCol = 'N'`

Comment: Spend some time creating an example that makes sense instead of telling us to write nonsensical queries

Comment: @MartinSmith Please feel no pressure to write a nonsensical query - that's the last thing I want. But just to be clear, nonsensical questions do not necessarily imply nonsensical answers. I have updated the question with information that I think is more than necessary to answer the question.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos As I indicated in the question, `L` does not yet exist in the code but it's there in reality. So I would like to know if this is possible to do in T-SQL only, without using other tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solved my issue and I guess it's far from the optimal way to do it.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable2 (MyCol2 VARCHAR(5))
INSERT INTO MyTable2 (MyCol2) VALUES ('A')
INSERT INTO MyTable2 (MyCol2) VALUES ('B')
.
.
.
INSERT INTO MyTable2 (MyCol2) VALUES ('N')
ALTER TABLE MyTable2 ADD ID INT IDENTITY

WHILE (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM MyTable2) > 0
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO MyTable1 (SomeCol1, SomeCol2)
  SELECT SomeCol1, SomeCol2 FROM SomeTable1 WHERE <conditions>
  UPDATE MyTable1 
  SET MyCol1 = (SELECT MyCol2 FROM MyTable2 HAVING ID = MIN(ID)) 
  WHERE MyCol1 = 'the default value of MyCol1'
  DELETE FROM MyTable2 WHERE MyCol2 = (SELECT MyCol2 FROM MyTable2 HAVING ID = MIN(ID))
END
```

Comment: It is good, to provide the character list as a table. No need to trick around like in my answer. But - to use your words - : Far more useful was some sample input and the expected output. I can tell you for sure(!), that your approach is - again your words - far from the optimal way... But without a better understanding it is pure guessing...

Comment: I see your point. I guess many people want to approach these questions with the mindset: "what is the optimal solution to this issue?". In that case, any background info helps. But that approach can end up in complex discussions, which is why I try to delimit the issue so that it can be solved more simply - in which case the one trying to answer the question needs to trust the formulation of the question, instead of references to the XY-problem. The answer I provided does not need any more information than already stated in the question, and it is enough for me for now (although sub-optimal).

Comment: Well, I see your point too, but I think it is not correct. Just imagine experts on the other side. Your "solution" is **so** far away from `T-SQL`, that an *expert* would never provide such an answer. Ask a great cook how to prepare Pizza with cheap convenience products. Do you think you'd get an answer? I'm pretty sure, that there won't be complex discussions on the *best solutions*. In the worst cast you get several answers with different approaches. Than you can pick the one you like most...

Comment: Thank you for the input. In any case, irrespective of whether or not we agree with each other, I really appreciate you taking the time to comment and post answers. Cheers! :)

Answer (score 4):

Your question is very unclear...

SQL-Server is a *set-based* tool. Whenever you feel the need to *loop / iterate* over a set you are assumably approaching your issue from the wrong side.

First question: How are you providing your *list of characters*? Is it a table, JSON, XML, a CSV-String?

In any case your goal must be to get it as a **set**.

Just to show the principles: If you provide your characters e.g. as a simple list you can use a recursive CTE

```
DECLARE @L VARCHAR(100)='ACFHJTZJ'; --add as many as you need

WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Pos,SUBSTRING(@L,1,1) AS OneChar
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.Pos+1, SUBSTRING(@L,r.Pos+1,1)
    FROM recCTE r
    WHERE r.Pos<LEN(@L)
)
SELECT /*add DISTINCT if you want to surpress repeating characters*/ 
       Pos,OneChar 
FROM recCTE;
```

This will return all letters as a derived table.

You can use such a set (however you create it) in a set-based statement like here:

```
DECLARE @L VARCHAR(100)='ACFHJTZJ'; --add as many as you need
DECLARE @tbl TABLE(SomeColumn CHAR(1));

WITH recCTE AS
(
    SELECT 1 AS Pos,SUBSTRING(@L,1,1) AS OneChar
    UNION ALL
    SELECT r.Pos+1, SUBSTRING(@L,r.Pos+1,1)
    FROM recCTE r
    WHERE r.Pos<LEN(@L)
)
INSERT INTO @tbl(SomeColumn)
SELECT DISTINCT OneChar 
FROM recCTE;

SELECT * FROM @tbl;
```

This would insert each separate `char` into the table `@tbl`. Of course you can use this in any other context (like a `WHERE` condition) too.

In any case, this statement would not have to change whether your list includes 1, 10 or a thousand of elements.

If you need more help, you really should provide more background information. Best was to create a *stand-alone* scenario as I've done above. And you might want to read about the XY-Problem...

Comment: Thanks! Far more useful than some of the other bitter comments :)